# Do sparse DAGs can have large min-cuts?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

For a graph $G$, let $e(G)$ denote the number of its edges, and $c_k(G)$ the smallest number
of edges that must be removed in order to destroy all paths of length $\geq k+1$.
Note that $c_1(G)\geq c_2(G)\geq \ldots\geq c_k(G)\geq \ldots$.
Let $K_n$ be a complete graph, and $T_n$ a complete acyclic digraph ([transitive tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29)) on $n$
vertices; hence $e(K_n)=e(T_n)=\tbinom{n}{2}$.

A classical [result](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1959-10.pdf) of Erdős and Gallai
states that 
$$
c_k(K_n)=e(K_n)-\frac{kn}{2}.
$$
In contrast, for the directed acyclic analogue $T_n$ of $K_n$, we have
$$
c_k(T_n)= k\binom{n/k}{2}=\frac{e(T_n)}{k}+\frac{n}{2}\Big(1-\frac{1}{k}\Big).
$$
**Proof:** To show $c_k(T_n)\leq k\tbinom{n/k}{2}$, take a topological order of vertices of $T_n$: 
vertices $i$ and $j$ are adjacent iff
$i < j$. Split the vertices into $k$ consecutive intervals of length $n/k$. If we remove all
edges whose both endpoints lie in the same interval, then we destroy all paths of length $\geq k+1$. 
 Since only $k\tbinom{n/k}{2}$ edges were removed, we are done.

The other direction $c_k(T_n)\geq k\tbinom{n/k}{2}$ was essentially shown
by David Eppstein in this [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/how-many-disjoint-edge-cuts-a-dag-must-have):
Let $C$ be a set of edges whose removal destroys all paths of length $≥k+1$ in $T_n$. Split the vertices into $t\leq k$ layers, where the $i$-th layer
contains all vertices $u$ such that the length of a longest path to $u$ in $T_n\setminus C$
 has length $i$. Since each layer is a layer of the *longest-path* layering,
it is independent in $T_n\setminus C$, and therefore complete in $C$.
Thus, if $n_i$ is the number of vertices in the $i$-th layer, then
the total number of edges in $C$ is at least
$\sum_{i=1}^t\tbinom{n_i}{2}\geq t\tbinom{n/t}{2}\geq k\tbinom{n/k}{2}$, as desired. 
Q.E.D.

Motivated by this (remarkable) difference between $c_k(K_n)$ and $c_k(T_n)$, here is my

> **Question:**
> Does $c_k(G)$ is at most "about" $e(G)/k$ for *every* acyclic digraph $G$?

By "about" I mean  "times some absolute constant or times some slowly growing function in $n$".

Note that the problem is only to get rid with graphs having also short paths (shorter than $k$), 
because $c_1(G)\leq e(G)/t$ holds
for any (not necessarily acyclic) digraph $G$, where $t$ is the length of a shortest source-to-target path. This is a direct consequence of
a dual to
[Menger’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem) (attributed to Robacker):
in any directed graph, the *minimum* length $t$ of a path is equal
to the *maximum* number of edge-disjoint cuts. (The proof is elementary, see e.g.
[here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/how-many-disjoint-edge-cuts-a-dag-must-have).)

Besides being natural in itself, an affirmative answer to my question would have some interesting consequences in [boolean function complexity](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/boolean/index.html) (see [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/how-many-disjoint-edge-cuts-a-dag-must-have) post and references herein).

Answer (score 5):

I just realized that the answer
to my question is (as suspected) NO. 
Namely, in [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439758290113X) paper, Georg Schnitger constructed a directed acyclic graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, and
$e(G)\approx n\log n$ edges such that, for every $0\leq \epsilon < 1$ and $k=n^{\epsilon}$,
we have that $c_k(G)\geq \alpha\cdot e(G)$, where $\alpha=\alpha(\epsilon)$ is a *constant*
depending only on $\epsilon$. This is much larger than the "desired" upper bound
$c_k(G)\leq e(G)/k$. Actually, I think that using the [Kraft inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%27s_inequality), one can show  that
$c_k(G)=\Omega(n\log(n/k))$ holds for every $k$: show that at least $m\log m$ edges must be removed in order to disconnect any given subset of $m$ leaves, and use the argument of the proof above (haven't verified the details yet).

The graph $G$ is constructed as follows.

[image]   [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/georg.jpg)

Take a complete binary tree of depth $t$; hence, we have $n=2^{t+1}-1$ vertices. 
Remove all edges. Connect
each vertex with all leaves, which were previously its descendants. Direct the new
edges in the following way: the vertex receives edges from his left leaves and sends
edges to his right leaves.

This example also shows the optimality of depth-reductions
for DAGs proved by  [Erdős, Graham and Szemerédi](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-26.pdf), and generalized by
[Valiant](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-08353-7_135?LI=true) to the following important fact:

> In a DAG with $m$ edges and depth (maximum length of a path) $d$, 
> it is enough to take out $mr/\log d$ edges to
> reduce the depth to $d/2^r$.